Laplace equation boundary condition
I'm reading a paper and seeing that the boundary condition for solving Laplace equation is set to
$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} = 0 $
just because there is no charge at that boundary.


Does this make sense? There is a sheet charge at the boundary where $y = a$, and since no charge is present inside the boundary the field due to the sheet charge would be present at the boundary where $y=0$.
Is there any reason why when solving Laplace equation if there is no charge at the boundary we can assume
$\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} $ is zero?

Two things are required:

That there is no charge at that boundary,
And the field is zero at the other side of that boundary.

With only requirement 1), you could draw an arbitrary line anywhere, without adding charge, and call it a boundary without charge. But $\partial V/\partial y$ would then just remain what it was before. (The text you show actually does state that the "field outside the depletion region is negligible", so in that step of the analysis requirement 2) seems to be acknowledged.)

Thank you for your comment, I assume you mean the boundary $y=a$ by "the other side of that boundary". In that case isn't the field $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}$ at that boundary? Therefore the field at $y=0$ should also be $\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}$. I think the field outside the depletion region is negligible justifies the boundary condition at $x=0$, since outside the depletion regions is where $x<0$ and $y>a$

You have two boundaries here, the "other sides" are $y<0$ and $y>a$, the sides where you do not want to compute the solution. The question at the end of what you write, whether: "no charge at the boundary" woud lead to $\partial V/\partial y=0$, has the answer "no", regardless of which boundary you mean. Absence of charge only means that $\partial V/\partial y$ will be equal on both sides.
